# imitate jQuery's toggle in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am attempting to transform a jQuery function to work with Angular. For the most part it is working (rather poorly) other than it keeps adding elements instead of removing the old (aka not toggling). I need one box to disappear as the other is opened. Any help accomplishing that is appreciated. Also any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/ENEpPd

HTML:

```
    <div id="Main" data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="starWarsCtrl">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div ng-repeat="character in characters" class="rowBox">
            <div ng-click="expand()" class="rowBoxLogo" id="{{character.name}}">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature/1" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
      var app = angular.module("app", [
]);

app.factory("Characters", function () {
    var Characters = [
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
     "index":88,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Yoda",
     "index":69,
      "cat":"jedi"},
    {"name": "Lando",
     "index":31,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Han Solo",
     "index":90,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Darth Vader",
     "index":98,
      "cat": "sith"},
    {"name": "Jar-Jar Binks",
     "index":80,
      "cat": "alien"},
    {"name": "Mace Windu",
     "index":45,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Chewy",
     "index":76,
      "cat": "smuggler"}
  ];
    return Characters;
});

app.controller('starWarsCtrl', function ($scope, Characters) {
  $scope.characters = Characters;
    $scope.expand = function(){
        var $info = $('<div class="expand"><p class="par"></p></div>');
            $('.rowBoxLogo').click(function() {
                var $block = $(this).parent('.rowBox');
                if ($block.next().hasClass('.rowInfo')) {
                    $info.toggle();
                }
                else {
                    $info.insertAfter($block).css('display', 'block');
                    $info.find('.par').text("ID = " + this.id);
                }
            });
    }

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do again? You attach a jQuery event handler within your expand function, which itself is a handler for a click function, which doesn't make any sense honestly.

Comment: I am attempting to "angularize" a jQuery function with limited knowledge of both so it is a mess. The easiest way to see what I am trying to accomplish is to click the boxes on my CodePen. A div is inserted under the current row but for some reason if another is clicked it opens another instead of replacing. I apologize, my programming terms/skills are small.

Comment: I'd rip all of that out and use angular for everything. the way to toggle in angular is to use the `ng-show` or `ng-if` directive to control the visibility (or existence) of the pre-existing DOM nodes. This really means rethinking your code structure so that the pieces are already there, and you're controlling their existence/display via properties on your model. For instance you might have a `character.expanded` property, and have your div already there with `ng-show="character.expanded"` then make your `ng-click` function do something like `character.expanded = !character.expanded`.

Comment: Honestly I did not notice I left the click handler in my function. Working on removing that now. No reason to duplicate functionality. I think that is why it was not running on first click.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan that gives some great direction. It seems to me that the reason why what I am doing is so difficult is because I am trying to merge two concepts (jQuery and Angular) instead of running with Angular completely. I'm struggling to mimic the functionality of staying under current items row when I do it in angular :/

Comment: Oh, trust me, I know it's a hard transition, and it takes a while to really grok what AngularJS is trying to get you to do. I've been using AngularJS for the last couple of years and I still say to myself, "this would be easier if I was using jQuery", but eventually you get into the mindset. Obviously my next job will use jQuery only and I'll be muttering "this would be easier if I was using AngularJS" :).

Answer (score 0):

you could make a new scope variable $scope.expandedCharacterId that is initially null.

when a character is selected (or perhaps deselected), expand(character) is called which sets $scope.expandedCharacterId

then on each character, have ng-class="{expanded: character.id == expandedCharacterId}"

that way, the selected character will be given an expanded class if it's selected. (you could just use ng-if or ng-show instead, but by using a class, you can use the power of css transitions etc.)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it seems that this if condition is never satisfied:

```
if ($block.next().hasClass('.rowInfo'))
```

Which makes sense as I don't see anywhere you've added that class anywhere in your code.

Chnage your expand method like this and it will work:

```
$scope.expand = function(id){
    console.log(id);
    var $info = $('<div class="expand"><p class="par"></p></div>');
    var $block = $('#' + id).parent();

    $('.expand').hide();
    $info.insertAfter($block).css('display', 'block');
    $info.find('.par').text("ID = " + id);      
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I updated the CodePen. `.rowInfo` is changed to `.expand` but the problem persists.

Comment: I am bit lost here since you used expand in ng-click and then inside expand you're again hooking into click of the same div? is that what you want? @JediCoder

Comment: No, it was pointed out to me that I left the jQuery click handler in my function. That is not meant to be there, I apologize.

Comment: see the update @JediCoder, and don't forget to pass the id into expand in your html

Comment: I implemented the changes you suggested and console is saying 'undefined' http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/BQxRby I'm sure I'm missing something simple but if you could take a look that would be amazing. @YaserAdelMehraban